# NextJS Page Routing

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am creating a personal website with NextJS and having issues with the new `app` directory.

I have a list of pages on my main `app/page.js` page, ex: About, Blogs, etc.. On my `/blogs` page, I want to include a list of blog posts that should redirect to that page and show the content of that blog, however I am receiving an unexpected 404 page not found when clicking onto my blog post.

Structure:

```
app/
  blog/
    page.js
    blog1.js
```

Inside of `/blog/page.js` I have the following code:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Blog() {
    const blogList = [
        {
            'page': '/blog/blog1',
            'text': 'blog 1'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Blog</h1>
            <ul>
                {blogList.map(blog => (
                    <li>
                        <Link href={blog.page}>{blog.text}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would appreciate some eyes and comments! Implementing this was easy with the `pages` directory, but this changed with v.13 and I haven't been able to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have this structure.

```
app/
  blog/
    page.js
    /blog1
       page.js
```

the routing in `app` directory is determined by the folder name and inside you need to have `page.js`

See more about here: [Defining Routes on Next.js 13](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes)